# WP Genesis - Breadcrumbs – Remove certain categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

I have an article which has two categories:

1. Featured Post
2. News

When I read the Article the breadcrumb is `Home > Featured Post > Post Title`

How can I achieve that the category “Featured Post” is never displayed in the breadcrumb, Genesis should show the second Category “News” instead. Is there a filter that I can use to exclude certain categories?

Thanks.

Comment: you need to change parmalink for this i think?

Comment: The url ist just domain.com/posttitle ... So the category is not visible in the url...